# creating a new gstelement object tee

Tags: gstreamer

I have created a new object of GstElement tee. The code is below here:

GstElement *teeElement = gst_element_factory_make ("tee", "camera_tee");

But, GstElement is not created at all. What can be the reason for this.

What library and/or header file has to be included for the purpose.

Regards,
iSight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to initialize gstreammer using gst_init.